# How can I use NDSolve with a variable parameter?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm a new user and I can't understand how to solve this function for variable values of `vr` (for example `vr` from 0 to 5 in steps of 0.01):

```
s = 
  NDSolve[{
    (1/Pi)^2*(1 + k*Sin[th[zr]]^2)*th''[zr] + 
      (1/Pi)^2*k*Sin[th[zr]]*Cos[th[zr]]*(th'[zr])^2 + 
        vr^2*Sin[th[zr]]*Cos[th[zr]] == 0, 
    th[0] == 0.0, th[1] == Pi/2},
    th, {zr, 0, 1}, 
    MaxSteps -> 1000];
```

In Matlab I can define a function and call it inside a For-loop, but in *Mathematica* so many things work differently.

Comment: Consider using `ParametricNDSolve[]`…

Comment: What about the other parameter `k`? What would you like to do with that one? Do you have a range you want to explore there as well, or do you have a single value in mind for it?

Answer (score 2):

I think for a Matlab user this would probably be something relatively simple to understand but still making decent use of Mathematica:

```
k = 1.0;
solution = Table[
  NDSolveValue[{
    (1/Pi)^2*(1 + k*Sin[th[zr]]^2)*th''[zr] + (1/Pi)^2*k*Sin[th[zr]]*
     Cos[th[zr]]*(th'[zr])^2 + vr^2*Sin[th[zr]]*Cos[th[zr]] == 0, 
    th[0] == 0.0, th[1] == Pi/2
   }, th, {zr, 0, 1}, MaxSteps -> 1000
 ],
 {vr, 0, 1, 0.5}
]
```

that will give you a list of results in form of interpolating functions. You can then use the following to plot the second solution (for `vr = 0.5` in my example):

```
Plot[solution[[2]][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

For your example the relatively new function `ParametericNDSolve` might be useful, as "Guess who it is" has suggested. This would work like this:

```
k = 1.0;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   (1/Pi)^2*(1 + k*Sin[th[zr]]^2)*th''[zr] + (1/Pi)^2*k*Sin[th[zr]]*
    Cos[th[zr]]*(th'[zr])^2 + vr^2*Sin[th[zr]]*Cos[th[zr]] == 0, 
   th[0] == 0.0, th[1] == Pi/2
  }, th, {zr, 0, 1}, {vr}, MaxSteps -> 1000
]
```

you can then plot the result for e.g. `vr=0.5` like this:

```
Plot[sol[0.5][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

and the following gives a simple interface where you can vary `vr` between 0 and 5:

```
 Manipulate[
  Plot[sol[vr][t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> vr], {vr, 0, 5}, 
  ContinuousAction -> False
]
```

As belisarius has mentioned the code above will have problems in version 9 (and not work with earlier versions as `ParametericNDSolve` was only introduced with version 9). It should work with at least 10.0.2 and also 10.1. It probably also is worth noting that I didn't make any checks whether the result are numerically correct or not. It is usually a good idea to do at least some checks for such results (but that isn't different when using matlab :-)...

Comment: It seems the solution gets in trouble  for `vr >1`

Comment: for me with 10.1 on Windows 7 64bit it gets slow, but seems work. Of course if you run into the update interval limit it might cause aborts. Which version are you running?

Comment: V9 here. It gets into `ParametricNDSolveValue::mxst`. Don't worry, perhaps correctd in v10. Thanks

Comment: @belisarius: I could verify that error message with version 9. Seems to be a bug which is corrected in at least 10.0.2 and also 10.1.0 (I haven't checked whether the result is numerically correct, though). I will probably add a note about that.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. K is a constant number